# P/Invoke or C++/CLI for wrapping a C library

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, pinvoke

We have a moderate size (40-odd function) C API that needs to be called from a C# project. The functions logically break up to form a few classes that will comprise the API presented to the rest of the project.

Are there any objective reasons to prefer P/Invoke or C++/CLI for the interoperability underneath that API, in terms of robustness, maintainability, deployment, ...?

The issues I could think of that might be, but aren't problematic are:

- C++/CLI will require a separate assembly; the P/Invoke classes can be in the main assembly. (We've already got multiple assemblies, and there'll be the C DLLs anyway, so not a major issue.)
- Performance doesn't seem to differ noticeably between the two methods.

Issues that I'm not sure about are:

- My feeling is C++/CLI will be easier to debug if there's an interop problem; is this true?
- Language familiarity - enough people know C# and C++, but knowledge of details of C++/CLI are rarer here.

Anything else?

Comment: Good question. I think C++/CLI is pretty cool in general so I'm interested in the answers.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the case where I am working with an existing C library, I prefer PInvoke.  PInvoke, while a bit tedious and troublesome at times, is a fairly well understood technology that has an ever growing set of tools and internet documentation available.  Generally speaking, whatever problem you run into, there is already a sample available on the web, or a quick check on stack overflow will provide a solution.

C++/CLI is a great technology, but IMHO its documentation is limited as compared to PInvoke for interop specific scenarios.  It also doesn't have the tooling infrastructure for interop solutions that PInvoke has.  Adding a C++/CLI assembly for a scenario that can be solved with PInvoke just seems too costly to me.

On the other hand, if I'm working with a large C++ library, I consider C++/CLI a bit more.  PInvoke does not work with C++, and I must end up adding some kind of intermediate layer.  Either a small C layer to wrap all of the C++ function calls or a C++/CLI library to bridge the gap.  C++/CLI feels a bit more natural to me in this case.

Answer (score 11):

It depends in large part how memory ownership is handled.  P/invoke can marshal pointers only when memory management is one of a couple particular ways, usually caller-allocated buffers.  If your API returns pointers (via return value or out parameter, doesn't matter) and expects them to be handed back to a destruction function later... p/invoke will either do the automatic marshaling or give you direct access to the pointer value you need to send back later, never both.  So C++/CLI becomes a very desirable approach in that case.

Comment: I'd have to double check but I think in this case the C library uses caller-allocated buffers everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

Think of P/Invoke as platform invocation, are you calling into something like the Win32 API which is very P/Invoke friendly or do you need to provide .NET bindings for an unmanaged library?

Since the wrapper typically is very thin a C++/CLI wrapper doesn't necessitate that you know C++/CLI specifically. What you need to know can be found in the [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-372.htm), it's an extensive documentation with lots of examples. P/Invoke is more of an nice to have feature for smaller well established existing libraries, but if the interface for calling into that library changes you'll run into a problem. With C++/CLI you can still have a public managed interface in your C++/CLI project that's exposed for managed code and handle changes to the C API more easily that way.

If you wanna get rid of the extra DLL you can always try ILMerge, but I'm not sure if it's capable of handling mixed assemblies, ([apparently not](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/1cabfef7-aec9-48bb-a2e4-a32dc1a027f4)), but it looks like it's possible to link both managed and unmanaged *.obj files with the PlatformSDK linker like this:

```
cl.exe /MD /c /clr Unmanaged.cpp
csc.exe /target:module /addmodule:*.obj Managed.cs
link.exe /DLL /LTCG /NOENTRY /CLRIMAGETYPE:IJW *.obj Managed.netmodule
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could link C# and C++/CLI obj files into the same assembly. Though in this case adding one assembly to the 15+ we already have won't be a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

C++/CLI will be easier to debug if you have personnel who know how to debug C++. If you don't, it could potentially be much harder.

I would suggest that the tradeoff here is between ease of use for the consumers of your interop assembly versus ease of maintainability for the assembly itself. If you have a solid core of senior engineers who are familiar with C++ and who can reliably maintain the assembly, it will be much easier on the rest of your team who are unfamiliar with native code to give them a fully managed interface that takes care of everything for them.

On the other hand, if you're the only person in the shop with C++ experience, I would be very leery of embedding a C++ module into the project, in case someone else has to maintain it later.

Comment: The majority of the current developers are familiar with C++ though only two or three have written any quantity of C++/CLI.

Answer (score 4):

For an API of this size (~40 total entry points), I would draw the dividing line between C++/CLI and P/Invoke based on how much "header file gunk" you must duplicate in C#.  If it's a small (to modest) amount, P/Invoke is fine.  Once you start duplicating a lot of .H files in C#—especially for things that aren't exposed in your .NET API—you might be better off using C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers here - another perspective is the plan for the existing C API.
Arguments for using PInvoke include:

- You need to keep a C API around for
  compatibility with other C consumers
- You need to keep the code in C as
  it's large and migration is too
  expensive

Arguments for using C++/CLI include:

- you want to move as much of the code as possible to the CLR

In this case you can start with C++/CLI and then move more and more over to C#

Comment: The C API is indeed used elsewhere and so will be staying around regardless of the choice made for this project.