# Using c# code from a native c++ application

Tags: c#, c++

I am working on a basic 2D C++ Game engine but i want to be able to use C# to make games with it like unity does but I'm not sure how to do it. I've seen people saying about CLI but not sure exactly how that works. I want to be able to access functions on the engine in C# and be able to have the engine run the C# code.

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: You probably should change your question title to something like: Using c# code from a native c++ application. You are not trying to spawn a c# compiler from your c++ application to build some unrelated c# project. With this said I am not sure this is an on-topic request. You basically want a tutorial.

Comment: There's a difference between a tutorial and just a name for the thing you're trying to do. It's hard to search something if you don't even know what it's called.

Comment: Where do you want `main` to be in?  Your C# EXE which loads your game engine?  Or does your game engine have its own EXE and `main` and loads you game logic from a .NET assembly?

Comment: Check this SO thread. P\Invoke or CLI for native managed communication.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561898/p-invoke-or-c-cli-for-wrapping-a-c-library

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you have two big ways of doing this:

1. Make your C# application generate COM objects which you can consume from C++. Performance is a bit iffy, but doable and very simple.
2. Use reverse PInvoke, where you export functions from your C++ application with `in` function pointers that you fill in from the C# side with delegates to the functions that drive your code.

In .Net 5, there's a third way: you can directly export C# functions from your assemblies to be consumed in a platform-independent way, like in C++ (ie, .dll or .so exports).

Comment: Would it be best to run the game from the engine or have the game use what it needs from the engine?

Comment: Generally the engine is the game, so I don't really know what you mean, but if you're asking which side should drive the application, C++ or C#, in an ideal world it's up to you. Right now it's a bit easier to drive it from C#, but in .Net 5 it's just as easy either way!